# Jquery Galleria pause and play on hover

Tags: jquery, galleria

I have implemented the jquery Galleria plugin in a website, but would like for it to pause when I hover my mouse over it and play again, when I remove the mouse.

How can I do this?

Thanks
Vayu

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [extend](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/options.rst) function to do that, like this:

```
$('.images').galleria({
    autoplay: true,
    extend: function() {
        var gallery = this;
        this.$('stage').hover(function() {
            gallery.pause();
        }, function() {
            gallery.play();
        });
    }
});
```